# Why does macOS Finder draw areas of my app icon where alpha != 1 in black?

Tags: macos, icons

When I select my app in Finder using the columns display, the app icon displayed in the rightmost pane has all areas where alpha != 1 rendered in black.

[Screenshot showing alpha!=1 areas in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0ps.png)
[image: Screenshot showing alpha!=1 areas in black]

However you can see the the icon in the middle pane is rendered correctly. Also if I view the app's .icns file in Finder it is rendered correctly:

[screen shot of app's .icns file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGwxV.png)
[image: screen shot of app's .icns file]

The icon is also rendered correctly in the Dock and in Launchpad.

Why does Finder render black in this one case?

macOS Sierra 10.12.5 but I doubt the issue is specific to this version.

I have spent almost a day hunting for solutions on the net but have not found anything even remotely close to this problem. No other app exhibits this issue. I have also tried to find an application that will let me view the details of each image of a working application's .icns file. Again without success.

Comment: Open the .icns in Preview.app then Tools > Show inspector, post the results back here.

Comment: Thank you I'L'I. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new *.icns* file using Image2Icon instead of Axialis IconWorkshop.

Following I'L'I's suggestion I examined the icon file with Preview. Preview shows that the 512x512 & 72x72 sizes do not have an alpha channel and have a black background where alpha != 1 in the 1024x1024 and other images that do have alpha. There are other strange images, including gray scale.

The *.icns* file was created for me by the icon designer using Axialis IconWorkshop. I do not have this software so do not know if the strangeness is cockpit error or application bugs.

I made a new *.icns* file from the same input PNG file using Image2Icon. In this file, all sizes have alpha and there are no strange images. Using this file, the display in Finder is correct.

Comment: Image2Icon instead of Axialis IconWorkshop did the job!  Your answer probably saved me days of searching.  And I do use Axialis on Windows; worked great for Windows .ics, but apparently not for Mac .icns.  Thanks!